# A better way to view fonts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

Are there any better way to view fonts in Photoshop (CS5.1 preferably) than this?:
[image: Photoshop's fonts menu]

EDIT: When i said 'better' i was trying to say: larger.

Comment: "better" how? I mean if you update to CC the document text will change as you flip through fonts in the list. -- Although I detest that feature and really wish it could be disabled, so I'm not sure that qualifies as "better".

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Metis you could do that before CC

Comment: I think it may have been added in CC1 @Ryan. Honestly you may be correct though. I cant recall exactly. I know CS5 didn't do it though.

Comment: In any case, Federico needs to [edit] elaborating on what is lacking for any reasonable answer to be provided.

Comment: There is no way to increase the menu text within Photoshop other than reducing the resolution of your monitor and making *everything* appear larger.

Comment: @Metis it updates if you do it trough the character with arrow keys in the character panel even in older illustrator versions. But again thsi is hardly conductive in a system that has a moderate amount of fonts. get a font manager.

Comment: Perhaps the free fontshop plugin will do what you want?  link [here](https://www.fontshop.com/content/fontshop-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

It's not within Photoshop itself, but [wordmark.it](https://wordmark.it/) is a website that displays all of the fonts on your computer. You can even filter selected fonts to further refine what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like Extensis. It would just be outside of PS. http://www.extensis.com/font-management/google-fonts/

Comment: Yeah, it's a cool solution. But today, i prefer a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I once printed a catalog of my fonts so I could flip through it when I have an idea of what kind of font I'd like to use. There are software options available that can help you print a catalog of fonts.

You could try something like this one: https://www.sttmedia.com/printmyfonts